# Finding transformation to meet linearity and homoscedasticity

Tags: r, data-transformation, heteroscedasticity, linear

In the picture below, what transformation on the response, just the predictor or both should be used to achieve  linearity and homoscedasticity.

[image]

they are plots of response(gestation period in weeks) vs predictor1(age of mother) and response vs predictor2(weight of mother)

Comment: What do the graphs show? What is your response (outcome, dependent variable) and what are your predictors? The y axis variable is seemingly integer-valued.

Comment: Better to ask the statistical question directly. (Is there an R package is off-topic: please see advice in the Help Center.  If it makes sense, you can use R or any other good software to answer it, even if you have to write your own code.)

Comment: @NickCox, they are plots of response(gestation period in weeks) vs predictor1(age of mother) and response vs predictor2(weight of mother)

Comment: I wouldn't expect gestation age to be conditionally or marginally normal at all. There must be literature in your field  on how such a response is handled: I don't need to underline its interest and importance. NB I'd expect over-plotting of identical data points to be a complicating factor here.

Comment: @NickCox, omm I am not sure what that field might be. I guess log transformations might be used, but it didn't change the graph much. All i can do now is guess and try various transformations..

Comment: I was guessing that you were in some medical science. Don't you know which field you are working in? But you can try thinking, not just trial and error. For example, gestation age is left-skewed so logarithmic transformation will clearly make any problem worse. I don't see much dependence on either predictor, but we can't tell for sure until and unless you post the data or identify a downloadable source. Making a not very good regression slightly better is not a very worthwhile exercise, but there may be more structure in the data than is evident.

Comment: omm I Googled: Original Mountain Marathon doesn't sound right.

Comment: Faced with these data I would just plot mean gestation age versus each distinct value or narrow bin of the predictors and as a check also median gestation age. If there is much structure in the data the means and medians will show it.